# Make ID the first attribute on input tag while using a repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I am using a asp:repeater but there is a tracking technology that needs the first attribute to be the id so it can make a bit by bit comparison.

The problem with this is that the repeater renders the control so that the name is the first attribute and then the type of the input, the id is the third attribute and I need to find a way to make it first.

Has anyone struggled with an issue like this?

```
<input name="repeater$ctl00$txtField" type="text" id="repeater_ctl00_txtField" class="gray" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using custom controls and take over rendering if you need particular order of attributes.

Comment: Wow. What is this tracking technology? Requiring attributes to be in a certain order is pretty silly requirement IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too elegant I guess, but using javascript;

```
...get the elements somehow

    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    var attributes = [];
    var attrId = '';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements[j].attributes.length; i++) {
        if (elements[j].attributes[i].name == 'id')
            attrId = elements[j].attributes[i].value;
        else
            attributes.push({
                'name': elements[j].attributes[i].name,
                'value': elements[j].attributes[i].value
            });
    }
    //Remove all attributes
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        elements[j].attributes.removeNamedItem(attributes[i]['name']);
    }
    //Add the id
    elements[j].setAttribute('id', attrId);
    //Add the rest
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        elements[j].setAttribute(attributes[i]['name'], attributes[i]['value']);
    }
}
```

BTW: Attr order does not matter, that tracking technology shoud be aware of it

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it defenetely point me into the right direction.

Comment: you're welcome, I'll update my answer in case someone else need it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this Felipe, it definitely point me into the right direction.

I did came across a couple issues, doing element.removeAttr on the type attribute caused it to fail with no error message, so I kept playing with it and found that

```
elements[j].attributes.removeNamedItem(attributes[i]['name']);
```

was able to remove this attribute properly, also trying to add the type attribute will fail the same way, again only for the type attribute, so I had to use this method for adding:

```
elements[j].setAttribute(attributes[i]['name'], attributes[i]['value']);
```

At the end your logic solved my issue, I just tweaked the methods a little bit. This is what I end up with:

```
for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
    var attributes = [];
    var attrId = '';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements[j].attributes.length; i++) {
        if (elements[j].attributes[i].name == 'id')
            attrId = elements[j].attributes[i].value;
        else
            attributes.push({
                'name': elements[j].attributes[i].name,
                'value': elements[j].attributes[i].value
            });
    }
    //Remove all attributes
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        elements[j].attributes.removeNamedItem(attributes[i]['name']);
    }
    //Add the id
    elements[j].setAttribute('id', attrId);
    //Add the rest
    for (i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
        elements[j].setAttribute(attributes[i]['name'], attributes[i]['value']);
    }
}
```

Thanks again Felipe :)